# de- serialize JSON metadata to .qvf using qlik sense API

Tags: qliksense

I am aware of Qlik sense serialize app where we generate a JSON object containing metadata information of a .qvf file using Qlik sense API.

I want to do a reverse operation of this i.e generate .qvf file back from json metadata.
After many research just found this link [github](http://github.com/mindspank/buildapp) and it doesnot have a complete information.

Any solution would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you cant create qvf directly from json. You'll have to create an empty `qvf` and then use various api to import the json.

Qlik have a very nice tool for un-build/build apps (and more). [qlik-cli](https://qlik.dev/libraries-and-tools/qlik-cli) have dedicated commands for un-build/build:

[image]

If you are looking for something more "programmable" then ive create some [enigma.js](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/) `mixin` for the same purpouse - [enigma-mixin](https://github.com/countnazgul/enigma-mixin#buildunbuild). I still need to perform more detailed testing there but it was working ok with simpler tests

#### Update 08/10/2021

Using `qlik-cli`

- setup [context](https://qlik.dev/libraries-and-tools/qlik-cli#get-started)
- first unbuild an app:

  `qlik app unbuild --app 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555`

  This will create new folder in the current folder named `<app_name>-unbuild`. The folder will contain all info about the app in `json` and/or `yaml` files
- once these files are available then you can use them to build another app. Just to mention that the target app should exists before the build is ran:

  `qlik.exe app build --config ./config.yml  --app 55555555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111`

  The above command will use all available files (specified in `config.yml`) and update the target app

  If you dont want all files to be used and only want to update the data connections, for example, then the build command can be ran with different arguments:

  `qlik.exe app build --connections ./connections.yml  --app 55555555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111`

  This command will only update the data connections in the target app and will not update anything else

Comment: could you tell me the command to build

Comment: updated my answer and added more details about build/unbuild with qlik-cli